# how to work with json elements in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

Sending data into the API with the following code

```
    signIn: async (email, senha) =>{
    try{
        const req = await fetch ( `${BASE_API}/Auth/login.php`,{
             method: 'POST',
             headers:{ Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
             body: JSON.stringify({email: email, senha: senha})
         });

         const json = await req.json();
         console.log(json);
         return json;
     } 
     catch(error){
         console.error(error);
     }
}
```

returns the following json that is being trown into console.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "user_avatar": "path",
    "user_celular": "00912341234",
    "user_email": "test@gmail.com",
    "user_id": "6",
    "user_mesa": "0",
    "user_nome": "Marcos",
    "user_senha": "testtest",
    "user_since": "2021-04-28",
    "user_sobrenome": "da Silva",
    "user_tipo": "0",
  },
]
```

how can I extract data from this json? for example: alert(json.user_nome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is this is not json this is the array object so if you want data from 1st object in array then you should use this...

```
json[0].user_nome
```

Or if you want all the user_nome property from all json object data then you have to use loop.

Comment: by the way, I should be using "fetch" in my API instead "fetchALL", thats why my response was getting an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Axios` is easier to use.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
.
.
.
.
  const [getdata, setdata] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Users", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        setdata(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: I actually use axios in other projects, but for educational purpose, im not using in this one, thanks anyway.